# IntelliJ memory issues

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA 12 for developing a Java Applications. I have the best experience for an IDE. It was working fine until recently. It started to show the heap size memory issue recommending to increase the Xmx and ask me to ignore or shutdown. The behaviour is weird as the IDE starts at 300 MB then it starts to take more memory until it reaches 750+ MB that's when it shows the problem.

I switched back to eclipse and the memory foot print is stable at 300 MB and doesn't increase by time like IntelliJ

Is IntelliJ doing some background process related to my code causing this increase? or is it a memory leakage problem with the IDE?

Answer (score 4):

I've used IDEA for 10 years (and used IDEA 12 for a year before switching to IDEA 13 EAP builds) and have never had a memory issue. And I do not see any consistent mention of memory issues in the IDEA forums.

That said, a memory leak was just fixed (as in released today) in the IDEA 13 EAP. The `VcsLogGraphTable` class had a leak. The [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116100) does not give any indication if the leak was/is present in IDEA 12. Based on the name of the class, it should only come into play for Git or Hg graphs (but Hg graphs were added in 13). Based on my experience with how they do tickets, I interpret this as an IDEA 13 issue.

First, make sure you are using the latest version 12.1.6.

Often times memory issues are a result of a poorly written third party plug-in. You can try to disable any third party plug-ins and see if the issue is resolved.

The other thing you can do is follow the instructions in the document *[How to report IntelliJ IDEA performance problems and take CPU snapshots](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192)* and report the issue to JetBrains. That way they can confirm a leak in IDEA 12, or tell you what plug-in is the culprit.

Comment: Wow 10 years!! Had no idea it is that old. I updated the Xmx to be 1024 instead of 750 MB and it didn't hang uphill now for 3 hours. I just hope it doesn't ask for more because I don't have any more. I just wonder why would it take 900 MB (current snapshot) when eclipse takes only 240 (N.B. IDEA starts with 300 MB and it keeps growing)

I don't have any plugins installed. If it persists, I believe I will upgrade to 13

Comment: It's actual about 13 years old :) Normally, JetBrains generally recommends that you not go higher than 700MB (at least when running in 32-bit mode). Higher values cause excessive garbage collection hangs. You can't really compare IDEA & Eclipse memory usage since the memory is not just the project, but the IDE itself. IDEA makes heavy use of indexes & caches for its features. It does sound like something is leaking. I hover around 350 with 2 projects and 550 with 3 large ones open. I think it'd be worthwhile for you to submit a memory snapshot to JetBrains via the doc I listed in my post.

Comment: I have v13.1.3, and it is getting progressively worse. Last time I opened it, it was using a GB of memory by the time my project's initial gradle build completed.